# How to get an specific relation in a Parse.com table/class (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform, relation

Been trying to figure this out with no avail, let's say each row in a table/class has several relations, how can I reference an specific relation from that row?... so I can do something with the third relation from row 1, for example.

Thanks.

Comment: A few more details about your particular setup would help us out quite a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just use something like this:

```
ParseRelation relation = ParseObject.getRelation("relationName");

ParseQuery query = relation.getQuery();
```

Then from there you can filter out your query results like:

```
query.whereEqualTo("Name", "Luchito");
```

And if I'm understanding your question correctly, you could then just take the list returned from query and compare it against another relation using whereEqualTo or whereContainedIn.

Comment: That makes sense... I've been doing something similar while getting specific rows, only wish there was a simpler method :/ something like `ParseObject object = ParseObject.getClass("Name").getRow(index)` instead of having to query first. Anyhow, it works adding .get(index) to the result list so thanks! :)